# Why Neo4j query is not returning wright data with first query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a strange issue I am unable to understand why the Neo4j query is returning different results.

```
WITH shipper
MATCH (shipper)<-[:SHIPPED_BY]-(shipment:ActiveShipment)-[:SHIP_TO_CITY]->(toCity)
      <-[:HAS_CITY]-(toState:State), 
      **(veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(shipment)-[:SHIP_FROM_CITY]->(frmCity:City)
      <-[:HAS_CITY]-(frmState:State)**
RETURN shipment, toCity, frmCity, frmState, veh
```

returns

[image]

but just making a slight change to the query gets me right results:

```
WITH shipper
MATCH (shipper)<-[:SHIPPED_BY]-(shipment:ActiveShipment)-[:SHIP_TO_CITY]->(toCity)
      <-[:HAS_CITY]-(toState:State), 
     (veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(shipment)
**MATCH (shipment)-[:SHIP_FROM_CITY]->(frmCity:City)<-[:HAS_CITY]-(frmState:State)**
RETURN shipment, toCity, frmCity, frmState, veh
```

which looks like this

[image]

Only difference between the shipments that is not returned from the one returned is that they have the same toCity and fromCity. Can someone please help me understand what is the issue with my first query?

**UPDATE**

its easy to reproduce,

`Create (st:State{Name:'ABC'})-[:HAS_CITY]->(c:City{Name:'XYZ'})<-[:SHIPPED_FROM]-(sh:Shipment{InternalId:1})-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]->(vh:Vehicle{Name:'Vheicle 1'}), (sh)-[:SHIPPED_TO]->(c)`

now if I add this query it will fail

`MATCH (shipment:Shipment)-[:SHIPPED_TO]->(toCity)
      <-[:HAS_CITY]-(toState:State), 
     (veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(shipment)-[:SHIPPED_FROM]->(frmCity:City)<-[:HAS_CITY]-(frmState:State)
RETURN shipment, toCity, frmCity, veh`

I think the issue is that same State appears twice, if i remove that it seams to work.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Would you be able to share your graph? E.g. in console.neo4j.org/r/blank ?

Comment: The only thing that quickly comes to mind is that in a single MATCH each relationship is allowed only once but with multiple match statements you remove that constraint, so it can match the same relationship again.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have updated the question to give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right same city having the same relationship to the same state,

as this is only additional information, you can also pull it out into a separate match clause.

like here:

```
MATCH (shipment:Shipment)-[:SHIPPED_TO]->(toCity)<-[:HAS_CITY]-(toState:State),(veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(shipment)-[:SHIPPED_FROM]->(frmCity:City)
MATCH (frmCity)<-[:HAS_CITY]-(frmState:State)
RETURN shipment, toCity, frmCity, veh
```